# Object detection using YoloV5 in C#

Tags: c#, object-detection, python.net, yolov5

I am new to ML and am trying to make inferences using the YoloV5 model from a C# program.  I am aware of the github port, but would like to use torch instead of ML.NET.  I found PythonNET nuget package, and this code is working:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Python.Runtime;

namespace Utilities.ML
{
    public class ObjectDetection
    {
        public static void Detect(string url)
        {
            Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Python38\python38.dll";
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic torch = Py.Import("torch");
                dynamic model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "yolov5s");
                dynamic img = url;
                dynamic results = model(img).pandas().xyxy[0].to_json();
                var str = results.ToString(); //Contains bounding box coords and class names in json format.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that each time I call this function, the model is loaded.  This is an expensive operation, and I am wondering if it would be a bad idea to persist the model object after it is loaded the first time Detect() is called.

Also, is this a bad solution for what I am trying to accomplish?  I don't have a ton of Python experience, but I'd imagine another way to tackle this would be to host a localhost REST API that my C# application could send requests to?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. You don't have to recompute `dynamic model` every time. Just ensure you have `Py.GIL` around `model(img)` calls.

Also if you have a GPU, torch models will likely be much faster if you pass multiple images at once to them.

Comment: You could also try TorchSharp

Comment: @LOST Thanks for letting me know about TorchSharp, I will look into that.  But I also understand the point you made in your first comment.  I mostly wanted to know if there was a better way of accomplishing this, but it seems this is sufficient.

Comment: @JohnWick Will You please tell me how did you do until now? I am also trying to use YOLOv5 in C# GUI. Will you please help me with the process?

Comment: @Virtuall.Kingg https://github.com/mentalstack/yolov5-net This library works great, check it out.  I'm using it now.

Comment: @JohnWick Thank you for your reply. I cloned the repo and followed the instruction. The build is also successful. But, I don't find the result.jpg image in the Asset folder. I did not make any extra changes except for installing the 'Install-Package Yolov5Net -Version 1.0.7' and for cpu 'Install-Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime -Version 1.9.0
'.  Will you help me with this, please? And I need to do real time streaming. Does it support that?

Comment: @Virtuall.Kingg I have seen some people using this for real time detection, but of course, there will be some latency, especially when inferring with the CPU rather than a GPU.

I'm not sure why you aren't getting an image outputted into the Asset folder.  Just try changing the path to a different folder on your PC.  If even that doesn't work, you can open an issue on the repo and I'm sure someone will help, it is being actively maintained.

Comment: @JohnWick If possible please provide me your email id. Or please mail me at dhiraj.ipcamp@gmail.com . I am in need of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as an answer for anyone else that is seeking a good way to use YOLOv5 in C#, that doesn't require dealing with python, since it is using ML.Net:

github.com/mentalstack/yolov5-net